# How to remove a node in igraph of visNetwork in R to see how removal influences community co-occurence network

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis, visnetwork

I created a cooccurence network with benthic genera. I am interested in seeing how the removal of a specific genera from the network can change the network structure overall. The interactive option in visNetwork, in which I can remove a node, does not seem to actually restructure the network based on the removal of the genera. It just eliminates it but keeps the rest of the network the same.

Furthermore, is there a way in igraph or visnetwork to see how many edges are connected to a particular node?

Comment: Please edit your post both here and at https://igraph.discourse.group/t/node-deletion-for-investigating-changes-in-networks-structure-counting-number-of-edges-to-a-given-node/1035 and cross-link the two versions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.